# CronJob: unknown field "configMapRef"

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-cronjob

I'm applying a **Kubernetes CronJob**.
So far it works.
Now I want to **add the environment variables**. (env: -name... see below)
While tryng to apply I get the error

> unknown field "configMapRef" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.EnvVarSource

I don't like to set all singles variables here. I prefer to link the configmap to not to double the variables. **How is it possible set a link to the configmap.yaml variables in a CronJob file, how to code it?**

Frank

```html
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: ad-sync
  creationTimestamp: 2019-02-15T09:10:20Z
  namespace: default
  selfLink: /apis/batch/v1beta1/namespaces/default/cronjobs/ad-sync
spec:
  concurrencyPolicy: Allow
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 3
  suspend: false
  schedule: "0 */1 * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    metadata:
      labels:
        job: ad-sync
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: ad-sync
            image: foo.azurecr.io/foobar/ad-sync
            command: ["dotnet", "AdSyncService.dll"]
            args: []
            env:
              - name: AdSyncService
                valueFrom:
                  configMapRef:
                    name: ad-sync-service-configmap
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Comment: Hi i think it should be configMapKeyRef

Answer (score 6):

There is no such field **configMapRef** in **env field** instead there is a field called **configMapKeyRef**

in order to get more detail about **kubernetes objects**, its convenient to use **kubectl explain --help**

for example if you would like to check all of the keys and their types you can use following command

```
kubectl explain cronJob --recursive

kubectl explain cronjob.spec.jobTemplate.spec.template.spec.containers.env.valueFrom.configMapKeyRef
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use [configMapKeyRef](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.13/#configmapkeyselector-v1-core) for single value or configMapRef with [envFrom](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.13/#envfromsource-v1-core)

Comment: links are broken

Answer (score 0):

It works this way:

```html
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  ...
spec:
  ...
  jobTemplate:
    metadata:
      ...
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: ad-sync
            ...
            envFrom:
              - configMapRef:
                  name: ad-sync-service-configmap
            command: ["dotnet", "AdSyncService.dll"]
```

Comment: it works but is not the same thing as you described in your example, please check my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches, using `valueFrom` for individual values or `envFrom` for multiple values.

`valueFrom` is used inside the  `env` attribute, like this:

```
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: ad-sync
        image: foo.azurecr.io/foobar/ad-sync
        command: ["dotnet", "AdSyncService.dll"]
        args: []
        env:
          - name: AdSyncService
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: ad-sync-service-configmap
                key: log_level
```

`envFrom` is used direct inside the `container` attribure like this:

```
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: ad-sync
        image: foo.azurecr.io/foobar/ad-sync
        command: ["dotnet", "AdSyncService.dll"]
        envFrom:
          - configMapRef:
              name: ad-sync-service-configmap
```

ConfigMap for reference:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: ad-sync-service-configmap
  namespace: default
data:
  log_level: INFO
```

The main difference on both is:

- `valueFrom` will inject the value of a a key from the referenced configMap
- `envFrom` will inject All configMap keys as environment variables

The main issue with you example is that you used the `configMapRef` from `envFrom` inside the `valueFrom` where should actually be configMapKeyRef.
Also, the `configMapKeyRef` need a key attribute to identify where the data is comming from.

For more details, please check in [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/) docs.